# Construtor classe abstract

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Não estou conseguindo desenvolver o seguinte ambiente:

```
public abstract class AplicacaoGenerica<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private IRepositorio<TEntity> repositorio;
    public AplicacaoGenerica(IRepositorio<TEntity> repo)
    {
        repositorio = repo;
    }

      (...)
}
```

Não apresenta nenhum erro esta classe.

```
public class BandeiraAplicacao : AplicacaoGenerica<Bandeira>
{

}
```

Nesta classe aparece o seguinte erro:

> does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

```
public class BandeiraAplicacaoConstrutor
{
    public static BandeiraAplicacao BandeiraAplicacaoEF()
    {
        return new BandeiraAplicacao(new BandeiraRepositorioEF());
    }
}
```

Apresenta o seguinte erro:

> does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Eu tenho uma classe abstrata, AplicacaoGenerica, que possui um construtor. Então crio uma classe BandeiraAplicacao que implementa AplicacaoGenerica. Então a Classe BandeiraAplicacaoConstrutor tenta chamar o construtor de BandeiraAplicacao.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem que criar um construtor com a mesma estrutura na sub `class`, algo similar a isso:

```
public class BandeiraAplicacao : AplicacaoGenerica<Bandeira>
{
     public BandeiraAplicacao(IRepositorio<TEntity> repo)
         // aqui estamos passando o argumento para a sub class 
         :base(repo)
     {
     }
}
```

O erro que você apontou está dizendo que a `class` base não tem nenhum construtor vazio, para a `class` `BandeiraAplicacao` utilizar em sua construção.

Então você tem duas opções para solucionar este problema:

1. Passar o parâmetro necessário a `class` base no construtor da filha (como no exemplo);
2. Criar um construtor vazio na `class` base;